# How use runtime.exec() to run code java another program?

Tags: java, process, cmd, runtime.exec

I have a program use runtime.exec() to compile and run code java. I put code need run into different directory with program. Code has method read integer from file, so when i run program to compile and run code java in directory then has error is file not found.
Who can help me run code java by cmd or use runtime.exec(command) to exec code java has read data from file?

Here is programe and code java need run.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
public class TestCodeJava {
  private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(ins));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(name + " " + line);
   }
}
private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
   Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
   pro.waitFor();
   String line = "";
  while((line = reader.readLine())!=null)
  {
       System.out.println(line);
  }
}
private static int toCompile(String fileToCompile)
{
  JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
  int compilationResult = compiler.run(null,  null, null, "-verbose", fileToCompile);
  return compilationResult;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    if(toCompile("E:\\Folder\\Prime.java")==0)
    {
       runProcess("java -cp \"E:\\Folder\" Prime");
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

}

```
import java.io.*;
public class Prime {
private static boolean isPrime(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1) return false;
    if(n == 2 || n == 3) return true;
    int m = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    for(int i = 5; i <= m; i = i + 5)
        if(n % i == 0 || n % (i+2) == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    File file = new File("INPUT.TXT");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    File file2 = new File("OUTPUT.TXT");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file2);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
    if(isPrime(n))
    {
        writer.write("YES");
    }else writer.write("NO");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Runtime.exec()`. Use a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: You need to give the full path to INPUT.TXT and OUTPUT.TXT instead of just the file name.

Comment: i had fix full path but program still filenotfound

Comment: Yes, thanks @r3ap3r, i had fixed but now i want code java can reed file same directory with it. Can you help me?

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.